# How does Spark decide how to partition an RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Suppose I create such an RDD (I am using *Pyspark*):

```
list_rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, 20, 2), 6)
```

then I print the partitioned elements with the `glom()` method and obtain

```
[[0], [2, 4], [6, 8], [10], [12, 14], [16, 18]]
```

How has Spark decided how to partition my list? Where does that specific choice of the elements come from? It could have coupled them differently, leaving some other elements than 0 and 10 alone, to create the 6 requested partitions. At a second run, the partitions are the same.

Using a larger range, with 29 elements, I get partitions in the pattern of 2 elements followed by three elements:

```
list_rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, 30, 2), 6)
[[0, 2], [4, 6, 8], [10, 12], [14, 16, 18], [20, 22], [24, 26, 28]]
```

Using a smaller range of 9 elements I get

```
list_rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(0, 10, 2), 6)
[[], [0], [2], [4], [6], [8]]
```

So what I infer is that Spark is generating the partitions by splitting the list into a configuration where smallest possible is followed by larger collections, and repeated.

The question is if there is a reason behind this choice, which is very elegant, but does it also provide performance advantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specify a specific partitioner, then this is "random" in that it depends on the specific implementation of that RDD. In this case you can head to the [ParallelCollectionsRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ParallelCollectionRDD.scala) to dig into it further.

`getPartitions` is defined as:

```
val slices = ParallelCollectionRDD.slice(data, numSlices).toArray
slices.indices.map(i => new ParallelCollectionPartition(id, i, slices(i))).toArray
```

where `slice` is commented as (reformatted to fit better):

```
/**
* Slice a collection into numSlices sub-collections. 
* One extra thing we do here is to treat Range collections specially, 
* encoding the slices as other Ranges to minimize memory cost. 
* This makes it efficient to run Spark over RDDs representing large sets of numbers. 
* And if the collection is an inclusive Range, 
* we use inclusive range for the last slice.
*/
```

Note that there are some considerations with regards to memory. So, again, this is going to be specific to the implementation.